# Should we create mobile app in native or hybrid?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, native, hybrid

My company is looking to create a Mobile App and we are currently debating whether we should create the app in Native or Hybrid. We are getting push from our Mobile Web Team that keeping the app hybrid would save the business money on the long run as the same code will run across all devices. Are there definite criterias under which Native should be preferred over Mobile?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are interested in following rule of thumb approach then you should be building the app in native. For a mobile application the default should always be native, doing hybrid is doing a half baked solution and maybe you should consider if it is even worth implementing the solution. The best take i found on Mobile vs Hybrid is present at the below tech blog, i would highly recommend going though it.
https://navdeepmahajantechblogs.blogspot.com/2018/05/native-vs-mobile-app-development.html

Comment: Really liked the article, thanks for sharing.